# I'm using Brad Frost's 3-up Carousel, I'd like to add a circular wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/pgjav

Hi, does anyone know how I could add a circular wrap to this carousel?

I'm a bit of a novice with javascript and I'm unsure of where to add the "wrap:circular" code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 3-up carousel is meant to be a proof of concept more than anything else, so I wouldn't recommend using it in production.

Check out the Filament Group's [Overthrow Sidescroller](http://filamentgroup.github.io/Overthrow-Sidescroller/) for a more robust, better-tested solution.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll check it out.